# How to replace chars in string from array of indexes?

Tags: python, string, char

Let's say that I have an empty array:

```
ws = []
```

And string:

```
text = "cmon lets go"
```

I will check for whitespaces and store index of whitespace in ws array so after that I'll have:

```
ws = [4, 9]
```

Then I'll have some other string:

```
new_string = "cmonzletszgo"
```

Where all whitespaces are switched with let's say letter z (does not matter).
Now I want to iterate over new_string and replace characters from indexes in array ws with whitespaces so I want to get

```
new_string = "cmon lets go"
```

Comment: Are these two questions or one? I don't see how your list of indices relates to the other one with the z in the strings. The former just appears to be a use of the `replace()` method for a `str` type. ```new_string = new_string.replace('z', ' ')```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the indices you want to replace, you might want to try iterating over `ws` instead of `new_string`:

```py
for i in ws:
   new_string = new_string[:i] + ' ' + new_string[i + 1:]
```

This will replace characters in `new_string` with white spaces at indices specified in `ws`, regardless of what character may currently be there.

Answer (score 0):

I'll just consider the first part, which is a one-liner.

```
ws = [i for i, ch in enumerate(text) if ch.isspace()]
```

I missed a key point in the second part, where the intent was to use ws to do the replacing. Again, a one-liner:

```
new_string = ''.join([' ' if i in ws else ch for i, ch in enumeration(new_string)])
```